# Android x86 Kernel Compilation stops abruptly

Tags: linux-kernel, android-x86, android-kernel

I downloaded PrimeOS' kernel from https://github.com/primebook/android_kernel_common. I just need to replace a single `.c` file in `/drivers/platform/x86`. Here's what I tried doing:-

1. Replaced `.c`
2. make clean && make mrproper
3. Copied `arch//configs/android-x86_deconfig` to linux source root folder as `.config`
4. fakeroot make kernel -j4

The command runs but stops abruptly and the terminal shows the `$` localhost as if the task is finished. Can you tell me where I went wrong.

Update
Here's the place where the issue comes:-

```
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
```

..............................................................

```
  CC      kernel/time/timeconv.o
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:3,
                 from ./include/linux/string.h:20,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page_32.h:35,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/page.h:14,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:12,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/gfp.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:10,
                 from ./include/linux/ring_buffer.h:5,
                 from kernel/trace/trace.c:15:
In function ‘ftrace_dump’,
    inlined from ‘ftrace_dump’ at kernel/trace/trace.c:8269:6:
./arch/x86/include/asm/string_32.h:325:29: warning: ‘__builtin_memset’ offset [8297, 8336] from the object at ‘iter’ is out of the bounds of referenced subobject ‘seq’ with type ‘struct trace_seq’ at offset 4176 [-Warray-bounds]
  325 | #define memset(s, c, count) __builtin_memset(s, c, count)
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
kernel/trace/trace.c:8347:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘memset’
 8347 |   memset(&iter.seq, 0,
      |   ^~~~~~
  CC      kernel/time/timecounter.o
```

..............................................................

```
   AR      kernel/built-in.a
   $
```

Full Log: https://pastebin.com/8T3G3Uyc

So, it just comes back to $ as if the process completed at kernel/built-in.a. This is the file where every time it stops. Even if I compile the kernel without any changes, it still stops at kernel/built-in.a
BTW, I am just using the source I downloaded from primebook and installed the necessary packages for recompiling the kernel. Should I be doing something else too.

**UPDATE 1**
I tried running make -j4 bzImage modules but this again stops at

```
    AR      drivers/video/built-in.a
    AR      drivers/built-in.a
```

Even this doesn't compile a bzImage

**UPDATE 2**
I tried running `make kernel` on a Linux source (5.4.0) and even that stops at `built-in.a`

**UPDATE 3**
I tried running `make bzImage modules` without `-j4` and I get a new error now

```
    sound/soc/codecs/es8316.c:766:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘module_i2c_driver’
    766 | module_i2c_driver(es8316_i2c_driver);
    | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
    make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:304: sound/soc/codecs/es8316.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:544: sound/soc/codecs] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:544: sound/soc] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:1050: sound] Error 2
```

Full log: https://pastebin.com/JJeh4QTk

**UPDATE 4**
`make bzImage`works and outputs the bzImage as expected.

Comment: Show the change, show the error!

Comment: i would recommend check that in two steps. First is check the build without your changes, second check with your changes.

Comment: @0andriy I am sorry I just added the data you asked.

Comment: @blandger I face the same issues. It still stops at the same line built-in.a even without any changes

Comment: `In function ‘ftrace_dump’,

..............................................................` what happened here? What is in that function? What do those dots represent? Are the dots part of `make` output?? When in doubt, post ALL the output, not some random snippets of it..

Comment: @NoobYT so your problem is just build that sources first. I'm not a experienced C user, I can just advice you to 'check twice sources consistency', if they were NOT broken during downloading/copying.

Comment: @KamilCuk Again, sorry new to this. I just have the whole log on pastebin - https://pastebin.com/8T3G3Uyc

Comment: @blandger Okay, I will try that

Comment: You compiled the kernel successfully - this is a warning, not an error. Did you expect something else? You said it "stops abruptly" - it compiles and then stops, doesn't seem to be "abruptly" to me. The warning is still concerning nonetheless.

Comment: But, I don't see the compiled Kernel file anywhere.

Comment: `I don't see` How do you "see" it? What are you expecting to find? (Please be specific) Didn't you want to `make all` instead of `make kernel`? I think `make kernel` only builds the things in `kernel/*`, so they got compiled (but maybe i'm wrong).

Comment: @KamilCuk I am looking for a file named kernel as my output. But, it's nowhere to be seen. After the make kernel command, if I am not wrong, a file named kernel should be produced, as seen here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Android-x86/x5aBNnK4Ols. But, I dont get it.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am pretty new to Android x86 kernels, though have some experience with Linux kernels

Comment: @blandger I redownloaded the repo and it still doesn't work. It doesn't output the kernel file anywhere.

Comment: @KamilCuk It somehow keeps stopping at a built-in.a file without any output whatsoever. Please check the update

Comment: It means that the error is not what you posted. Run `make -j1 ...` instead of simple `make ...` to see it.

Comment: @0andriy Again it stopped at built-in.a without any output. It always stops at a built-in.a file though I have been able to compile a Linux kernel on this machine successfully
Please also check Update 2

Comment: @0andriy Check UPDATE 3 please. This time I get a new error

Answer (score 0):

**Fix for kernel compilation stopping at make a built-in.a file**

Use `make bzImage` or `make bzImage modules` instead of `make kernel`
*Update* - In my case the error was with the `ES8316.c` which was causing the compilation to stop. Go to your config file and delete the lines pertaining to ES8316 and the build went through successfully.

**Fix for other Errors in the question**

For the codec issue and for any other conflicting module, go to your config file and search for it, for eg:- i had issue with the module for ES8316. To fix it, remove the line corresponding to ES8316 in your config file or add a `#` infront of it. You may also try to debug the problem if you really need that driver.

**Other things that you could try**

- I had `gcc-9` installed and installing `gcc-8` did help at times.